# Where do I find rails locale files for different languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Where do I find activerecord and date translations for whatever language I'm trying to add to my site?

Comment: in config/locales.  have a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html for a run down on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Rails comes equipped with an I18n [framework / API](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), which like most such frameworks involves defining a message catalog for each supported language. In the case of Rails, catalogs are YAML files under `config/locales`.

Rails defines standard keys for general ActiveRecord validation messages, but only comes with English translations by default. An alternative to providing translations from scratch yourself is to install the `rails-i18n` gem ([svenfuchs/rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n)), which comes bundled with translations for many supported languages. These include both default ActiveRecord messages and assorted other things such as date and currency formats, days of the week, etc. You can mix and match the translations in `rails-i18n` with your own custom translations of course by adding your own locale files.

Note: The contributors to `rails-i18n` have done a great job, but not all locales have the full set of ActiveRecord messages, so in some cases you will have to provide your own (or consider contributing a pull request to the project).

**EDIT:**

The pre-defined catalogs that come with `rails-i18n` are installed with the gem. Running `bundle info rails-i18n` will show you the local install path; the locale files are in `rails/locale` if you want. Rails should find these automatically with further effort. So, in rails console:

```rb
foobar> I18n.locale = :tr
=> :tr
foobar> I18n.t 'time.pm'
=> "öğleden sonra"
```

You can extend or override the defaults by creating a custom locale file in your app's `config/locales` directory. The I18n search path will check `config/locales` before moving onto the default, so you only need to supply new or changed translations in your custom locale file.

Comment: already using it but i don't know how to get the yml file or generate it

Comment: I updated the answer, but tl;dr is they get installed with rails-i18n and Rails finds them automatically.

Comment: whatever that means